# Why does local variables built by pointers and by objects show different output

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to calculate average path length in my red black tree. I found something really weird. The code is shown below:

```
  while (dataSize<MaxSize) {
            int i = 0;
            double aveLengthArr[1000];
            while (i < 1000) {
                RedBlackTree rbt;
                int* array= generateRandomInput(dataSize);
                for (int n= 0; n < dataSize; n++) {
                    rbt->insert(array[n]);
                }
                aveLengthArr[i]=rbt->getAvePathLength();
                i++;
            }
            double mean = calAverage(aveLengthArr);
            double stdDeviation = calDeviation(aveLengthArr, mean);
            dataSize++;
        }
```

When a specific line code `RedBlackTree rbt;` is used, the average length is still the same with different  input `array` (I have already debugged it).
But when the code is changed to `RedBlackTree* rbt=new RedBlackTree;`,it get the right result and the length varies.

So I am really confused because `rbt` is a local variable, right? Every time the program jumps into a new loop, the `rbt` should be a totally new object. Even if it is not updated, the length should increase but it is not. After using a pointer, it is right.

Another weird thing is that when I run the program with code `RedBlackTree rbt;` in Window7, the result is right. When using Ubuntu, it shows the problem above.
Any idea is appreciated.It is really hard for me to figure it out.

The RedBlackTree is red black tree and I write it as a self-defined class.Part of the class is showed below:

```
class RedBlackTree {
private:
    Node* root;
    int redNodeNum;
    int totalPathLength;
public:
    RedBlackTree() {
        redNodeNum = 0;
        totalPathLength = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `RedBlackTree rbt; rbt->insert(array[n]);`? What's going on here? Is `RedBlackTree` some sort of a smart pointer?

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov It is a self-defined class about red black tree structure.@HostileFork give me a good explanation but I still want to figure out why ' RedBlackTree* rbt=new RedBlackTree ' works without initialize root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not initialize `root` in your constructor.

> Every time the program jump into a new loop, the rbt should be a totally new object.

The object is *constructed* each time.  But the memory is *probably* at the same address each time through the loop (this is not a guarantee).  And since you don't initialize `root`, you're seeing some undefined behavior, which again is *probably* keeping the last value from the loop...but would be sensitive to conditions of compilation, debugging, optimization...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

> Another weird thing is that when I run the program with code RedBlackTree rbt; in Window7, the result is right. When using Ubuntu, it shows the problem above.

This is the kind of thing that happens with undefined behavior.

> `rbt->insert(array[n])`

As @SergeyTachenov has pointed out, this likely won't compile since your RedBlackTree is not a pointer in the given code (so would have to be `rbt.insert(array[n])`.  It is probably an artifact of you copying something halfway between the pointer-based version and the non-pointer based one.

Posting a complete and coherent example is important, so please read about [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code in your question should ideally compile as-is [in an online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) and clearly demonstrate your problem.

Comment: But it does not explain why I change it to pointer and it works. And the code run in Window gets the right answer.

Comment: @SHUYULYU Yes it does explain it--read up on undefined behavior.  You will have to get away from the illusion of "and it works" in C++ programming...just because a program appears to work *under some circumstances of compilation and execution* does not mean it is correct.  It may pop up and surprise you while running if you have broken the rules of the language, even on the cases where it is appearing to work part or most of the time.

Comment: I will test it now and back to you soon.

Comment: I just test my code and output the element. It is overlapped and never changes. Your solution is perfect. It is caused by undefined behavior.